# Erro START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}

Tags: android, web-service

Ao acessar um webservice feito em php, no android me apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
 START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4e84b080)
```

JAVA/Android:

```
/**


* Created by brunno.nascimento on 19/12/2016.
 */
package br.com.brunnosena.portalaluno;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ExemploWS extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context context;

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "SaludoXMLwsdl#Saludar";
//private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "SaludoXMLwsdl#getUsuarioLogin";
//private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "getUsuarioLogin";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Saludar";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "SaludoXMLwsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://vagas.qi.edu.br/webservice/loginApp/webservice.php?wsdl";

public ExemploWS(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String result = null;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
            OPERATION_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER10);

    // Con esta opción indicamos que el web service no es .net
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    // Enviando un parámetro al web service
    request.addProperty("nombre", params[0]);

    try {

        // Enviando la petición al web service
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Recibiendo una respuesta del web service
        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                .getResponse();

        result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

        //httpTransport.getServiceConnection().disconnect();
    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.v("Error", e.getMessage());
        result = e.getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Mostramos la respuesta del web service
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

PHP:

// incluyendo la librería de nusopa
    require_once('nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php');

```
// Configurando el web service
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("SaludoXML", "urn:SaludoXMLwsdl");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = "urn:SaludoXMLwsdl";



// Registrando nuestra función Saludar con su parámetro nombre
$server->register(
        'Saludar', // Nombre del método
        array('nombre' => 'xsd:string'), // Parámetros de entrada
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'), // Parámetros de salida
        'urn:SaludoXMLwsdl', // Nombre del workspace
        'urn:SaludoXMLwsdl#Saludar', // Acción soap
        'rpc', // Estilo
        'encoded', // Uso
        'Saluda a la persona' // Documentación
);

// Nuestra función que proporcionaremos
    function Saludar($nombre) {
        return 'Hola ' . trim($nombre);
    }

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';   
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Comment: Bruno poste seu código, assim fica dificil ajudar, mostre qual metodo que está tentando consumir do webservice

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira

Comment: Porque você passa params[0]  para o request?

Comment: Faça um teste passando uma string "com algum nome" e sua versão do xml é  SoapEnvelope.VER10 mesmo? não é a 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olhei sua URL pelo SOAPUI e vi que a versão do seu xml é 1.1
 mude a linha

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER10);
```

Para

```
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

Comment: fiz o teste que me pediu.
Coloquei um nome qualquer, e na versão alterei para VER11.
Ainda persiste o mesmo erro.
Seguinte, coloquei no SOAP_ADDRESS" o endereço local do servidor, e funcionou. coloquei no meu dominio, e funcionou, Mas se eu colocar o a url, não funciona.

Comment: Pelo SoapUI Também tentei acessar pela sua URL ela me retorna um erro, @BrunnoSena

Comment: Access to the application you were trying to use has been blocked in accordance with company policy. Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is in error.  Essa mensagem vem em Um HTML e @BrunnoSena

Comment: poderia ser algum bloqueio no iis ? Sabe o que poderia ser isso ?

Comment: Provavelmente sim  o titulo desse HTML de retorno  Application Blocked, e você disse que está acessando normal com o endereço local.